# Rotate pdf file less than 90 degree?

Tags: pdf

How can I rotate a PDF file less than 90 degree under Ubuntu?

Can I do that interactively?

Comment: Is this even possible without rasterizing? I know you can do it with Postscript, but I don't know if PDF supports rotating everything at arbitrary angles.

Comment: @Gilles - I don't think you can rotate in degree increments. There's a flag in the PDF file that is being manipulated, but it's only in 90 degree increments from what I've found thus far.

Comment: @Gilles It certainly is, see my answer.

Comment: This has also been asked on [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29573189/rotating-pdfs-less-than-90-degrees).
I posted a LaTeX solution there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I looked hard and long and could find no tool that allowed you to do this interactively that is a native PDF viewer type of tool. I did not try this but you might be able to use Inkscape or Gimp to do this. I think the only issue you'll likely run into with using them is the ability to batch rotate a multi-page document.

Even the command line tools such as PdfTk couldn't do rotation by degrees, which really surprised me.

However using ImageMagick you can rotate PDF files in 1 degree increments.

#### Examples

```
$ convert original.pdf -rotate 45 rot45.pdf
```

You can put any value you want in for the rotate argument. It will also take negative numbers so this is possible:

```
$ convert original.pdf -rotate -45 rot-45.pdf
```

The quality of the output will drop off dramatically using the default options so you'll likely need to include the `-density` switch to increase the quality of the resulting PDF file.

```
$ convert -density 300x300 original.pdf -rotate 45 rot45.pdf
```

#### Resulting PDF

Here's a screenshot of Evince with the resulting PDF file.

[image: ss of pdf]

Comment: Imagemagick or Gimp rotate by first rasterizing, which is often not desirable.

Comment: @Gilles - yeah I know, I've been searching for another method, but coming up empty. There is an SU Q&A that shows using programmatic methods, but that seems a bit beyond what would be appropriate here. Have you found any other methods. There was a page I came across that said Acrobat Pro can do rotates by 1 degree increments but I couldn't tell if it was doing rasterizing too or not.

Comment: Thanks,slm! Can the method by `convert` rotate every page in a single multiple-page pdf file? @Gilles: in my case, the pdf files are created by scanning. So I think rasterizing first doesn't matter?

Comment: @Tim - yeah since they're scans they've already been rasterized. Yes it does every page.

Comment: @Tim - yes, that's what the example shows, it converted a multi-page document.

Comment: @slm: thanks! but it only convert the first page of one of my pdf files

Comment: @Tim - something must be up with that PDF file then. Where did it come from? The results above are exactly what I used and got. No doctoring of the screenshots was done 8-)

Comment: @slm: I realized the two pages of the pdf file need to rotate different angles. How can I do that?

Comment: @Tim - that's a different question. This one was asked and answered, I'd ask that as another question.

Comment: @slm: I followed the command `convert -density 300x300 original.pdf -rotate 45 rot45.pdf` to preserve the quality, but the size increases from 100KB to 2MB. What can I do to reduce the size without sacrificing the quality? I used a online compressing website http://compress.smallpdf.com/, but it takes forever to compress and hasn't finished yet.

Answer (score 7):

You can do that with [ConTeXt](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Main_Page).

- does not rasterize
- allows for individual angles for individual pages
- allows for varying page sizes

Versions before `2013.10.07 09:47` had a bug which cropped the pages, so make sure you use a version including the fix.

First create a file (e.g. `rotatepdf.tex`) with the following content

```
\getfiguredimensions [\getdocumentargument{input}]
\starttext
  \dorecurse{\noffigurepages}
    {\startTEXpage
      \externalfigure
        [\getdocumentargument{input}]
        [page=\recurselevel,
         orientation=\getdocumentargument{rotation}]
    \stopTEXpage}
\stoptext
```

Then you can rotate a PDF using the following command line:

```
context --input=somefile.pdf --rotation=10 rotatepdf.tex
```

Here is an example output:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

This has also been asked on [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29573189/rotating-pdfs-less-than-90-degrees).

Another option is using LaTeX:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics[angle=-1.5]{odd-scan}
\end{document}
```

In this case, I have the file `odd-scan.pdf` (a slightly rotated one page scan) in the same folder as the LaTeX file `rotated.tex` with the content above and then I run `pdflatex rotated.tex`. The output is a file `rotated.pdf` with the PDF rotated by 1.5 degrees clockwise.

Answer (score 1):

You could import it with GIMP, which includes a rotate tool and can export back to pdf.

Comment: Gimp rasterizes first, which is often not desirable.